# Pushing custom component in lightning:helpText

Tags: lightning

I am trying to have a custom component to show up in lightning:helpText component. As per the docs it says it has body[] attribute but when I am trying to get the value of it (it should give me array), it is coming as undefined. Does anyone has any idea what might be the case?

[image]

**Component code:**

```
<lightning:card>
    <lightning:helptext aura:id="helpText"
        content=" The tooltip displays on the lower left of the icon or above the icon if space is available. It automatically adjusts its position according to the viewport.">            
    </lightning:helptext>        
</lightning:card>
```

**Lighting Controller code:**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponent(
        "c:FancyHelpTextContent",
        {
        },
        function(fancyHelpTextContentComponent, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                debugger;  
                let  helpTextComponent =  component.find('helpText');     
                let body = helpTextComponent.get('v.body');
                //Expected that body should come as array of but it is returned as undefined
                //body.push(fancyHelpTextContentComponent);                                                                
                //helpTextComponent.set('v.body',body); No success with forceful set by creating body array
            }
        }
    );
}
```

})

If I create body array and try to set it then it is giving some aura internal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All components have a body attribute (because it is a part of `aura:baseComponent`), but not all components *use* that attribute. `lightning:helptext` uses `content`, which is a `String` attribute. You cannot put components inside that component, so if you want to do so, you'll have to write your own component based on SLDS if you want this functionality.

Comment: Thank you that confirms it. I will go with custom help text.